# Two conversions of practically the same number giving two different results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, cast, floating-point

To my surprise, I run the following queries in SQL Server 2014 and each returns a different result, as shown in [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=8f9376dd165d3d2da83114bdb7a19cb3)...

This

```
Select convert(numeric(19,2),convert(float,9.76499999999999999999999999))
```

gives *9.76*.

And this

```
Select convert(numeric(19,2),convert(float,9.7649999999999999999999))
```

gives *9.77*.

Can someone explain why one truncates while the other rounds up?
This is causing a nightmare for me.

I wish I could just stop using floats but they are all over our application, which has been ongoing for over 30 years.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, this behaviour changes in SQL Server 2016. When I try against 2017 with `COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 120` I see your observed behaviour. When `COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130` both input values produce the same rounded output value 9.77.

There is some documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#converting-decimal-and-numeric-data) but it is not conclusive. I do not have 2014 documentation to hand but it would be interesting to compare for differences.

You may find some helpful information in the Microsoft Support article [SQL Server and Azure SQL Database improvements in handling some data types and uncommon operations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4010261/sql-server-and-azure-sql-database-improvements-in-handling-data-types).